# MS Access Union Query Providing Inflated Results

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010, union

I have a union query that had worked in the past, and I honestly can't tell if for some reason I changed something or if there's something in the data tables that are causing the issue.

Below is a "shorter" version of the query, which is essentially merging two replica tables except one holds CY information, the other PY information and columns labeled accordingly. When I break out the two parts of the query for CY and PY separately, then the results are ok.

It's the union that's inflating some or all of the values now.  Is there any possible reason why?? Maybe where there are null values in the row value columns?

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT [CY 12Mths].BRANCH
        ,[CY 12Mths].VND_ID
        ,[CY 12Mths].PROD_ID
        ,Sum([CY 12Mths].TOTAL_ALLOWANCE_CY) AS SumOfTOTAL_ALLOWANCE_CY
        ,Sum([PY 12Mths].TOTAL_ALLOWANCE_PY) AS SumOfTOTAL_ALLOWANCE_PY
    FROM [CY 12Mths]
    LEFT JOIN [PY 12Mths] ON ([CY 12Mths].BRANCH = [PY 12Mths].BRANCH) ([CY 12Mths].VND_ID = [PY 12Mths].VND_ID)
        AND ([CY 12Mths].PROD_ID = [PY 12Mths].PROD_ID)
    GROUP BY [CY 12Mths].BRANCH
        ,[CY 12Mths].VND_ID
        ,[CY 12Mths].PROD_ID
    ORDER BY [CY 12Mths].BRANCH
        ,[CY 12Mths].VND_ID
        ,[CY 12Mths].PROD_ID
    ) CY
```

Comment: Sorry - the message is too long. How do I submit the sql? I've cut it down some, but can make it less characters.

Comment: Edit your question and put it there.

Comment: Use the [【Edit】](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38359297/edit) button on your post to add your code.

Comment: Still having a problem. Let me try something.

Comment: SELECT * FROM
    (
    SELECT [CY 12Mths].BRANCH, [CY 12Mths].VND_ID, [CY 12Mths].PROD_ID, Sum([CY 12Mths].TOTAL_ALLOWANCE_CY) AS SumOfTOTAL_ALLOWANCE_CY, Sum([PY 12Mths].TOTAL_ALLOWANCE_PY) AS SumOfTOTAL_ALLOWANCE_PY
    FROM [CY 12Mths] LEFT JOIN [PY 12Mths] ON ([CY 12Mths].BRANCH = [PY 12Mths].BRANCH) ([CY 12Mths].VND_ID = [PY 12Mths].VND_ID) AND ([CY 12Mths].PROD_ID = [PY 12Mths].PROD_ID)
    GROUP BY [CY 12Mths].BRANCH, [CY 12Mths].VND_ID, [CY 12Mths].PROD_ID
    ORDER BY [CY 12Mths].BRANCH, [CY 12Mths].VND_ID, [CY 12Mths].PROD_ID
    
    ) CY

Comment: @RARascon Please don't post code in the comment section.  Use the [【Edit】](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38359297/edit) button under your question to add it there.  (The Edit button is located right under your question tags).  Alternatively, you can click on the link in this comment to edit your post.

Comment: ok - I was trying a few things. Let me try again. Sorry - I thought I had done this before...

Comment: Ok - I think that worked. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: There is no UNION in that SQL...?

Comment: Correct - for some reason, I still can't seem to get both parts of the union query posted.  I keep getting an error. However, after reading some posts, I believe for some reason the RIGHT JOIN clause got changed to LEFT JOIN.  I'm testing it out now.

Comment: This query has worked in prior months, so I must have inadvertently changed something when I made a change to some of the columns.